# If an array has two items with same ID then compare and add key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of objects, if two objects in the array have the same ID I want to add the difference as new key value in the object. For example I have the array

```js
let array = [
  {id: 'apple', prop_name: 'price_l', last_value: {id: 390897, timestamp: 1673262338, prop_value: 10}},
  {id: 'orange', prop_name: 'price_g', last_value: {id: 390898, timestamp: 1673262338, prop_value: 8}},
  {id: 'apple', prop_name: 'quantity_a', last_value: {id: 390899, timestamp: 1673262338, prop_value: 12}},
  {id: 'orange', prop_name: 'quantity_o', last_value: {id: 390900, timestamp: 1673262338, prop_value: 14}}
];
```

And I want the output to be like this (labels may be dynamic)

```js
let array = [
  {id: 'apple', price_l: 10, quantity_a: 12},
  {id: 'orange', price_g: 8, quantity_o: 14}
];
```

Here's what I've tried so far

```js
function addKeyValuePair(array) {
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
          if (array[i].id=== array[j].id) {
           //I'm stuck here
          }
        }
      }
      return array;
    }

     console.log(addKeyValuePair(array));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are stuck because you are not using some sort of collector where you build the new objects in.

Here is a one-liner, where the new objects are collected as values of an object, adding prop names and values at each step:

```js
let array = [
    {id: 'apple', prop_name: 'price_l', last_value: {id: 390897, timestamp: 1673262338, prop_value: 10}},
    {id: 'orange', prop_name: 'price_g', last_value: {id: 390898, timestamp: 1673262338, prop_value: 8}},
    {id: 'apple', prop_name: 'quantity_a', last_value: {id: 390899, timestamp: 1673262338, prop_value: 12}},
    {id: 'orange', prop_name: 'quantity_o', last_value: {id: 390900, timestamp: 1673262338, prop_value: 14}}
  ];
  
const res = Object.values(array.reduce( (r, {id, prop_name, last_value:{prop_value}}) => ({...r, [id]: {...(r[id] ?? {id}), [prop_name]: prop_value} }), {}))
console.log(res)
```

Here it is verbose:

```js
let array = [
    {id: 'apple', prop_name: 'price_l', last_value: {id: 390897, timestamp: 1673262338, prop_value: 10}},
    {id: 'orange', prop_name: 'price_g', last_value: {id: 390898, timestamp: 1673262338, prop_value: 8}},
    {id: 'apple', prop_name: 'quantity_a', last_value: {id: 390899, timestamp: 1673262338, prop_value: 12}},
    {id: 'orange', prop_name: 'quantity_o', last_value: {id: 390900, timestamp: 1673262338, prop_value: 14}}
];

function wrap(arr){
  const collector = {}
  for(const entry of arr){
    const id = entry.id
    if (!collector[id]){
      collector[id] = {id}
    }
    collector[id][entry.prop_name] = entry.last_value.prop_value
  }
  return Object.values(collector)
}

console.log(wrap(array))
```

Comment: if have an extra pair in the object how to include it ?

Comment: @Viira what do you mean, an extra pair?